# How to use kotlin-native lib with JNA

Tags: java, kotlin, jna, kotlin-native

I'm trying to write a pretty simple application with JNA implementation, I want to use `kotlin-native` to create native lib.

kotlin: **calc.kt**

```
fun sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
  return a + b
}
```

java: **CalcJNA.java**

```java
interface CalcJNA extends Library {
   int sum(int a, int b);
}
```

**The Problem**

I'm getting the following exception, whatever if I declare `CalcJNA.sum` or `CalcJNA.Kotlin_Root_sum`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'sum': dlsym(0x7fcc6d42ac80, sum): symbol not found

I also try to use [kotlin.native.CName](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.native/-c-name/index.html), but I'm getting `Unresolved reference: native`

**Questions**

1. What's the proper way to declare kotlin native function signature in JNA?
2. How to setup `plugins { id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.3.41' }` to be able to use `@CName`?

Comment: Please look at [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/backend.native/tests/produce_dynamic/simple/hello.kt) example of `@CName` usage.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev i had already saw that example, but it isn't quite clean how to setup gradle to get `kotlin.native.CName` available. Actually I'm using `org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform` plugin

Comment: Are you sure that 1) your project structure is correct and 2) you wrote the `import ` directive in yours`.kt` file?

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev I started another project from scratch, now using version `1.3.21` and worked, later I'll try to update to latest version of the plugin. Anyway thanks.

Comment: If there will be something else, please let me know. It looks like a really strange problem.

Comment: Hey, It worked with version `1.3.41`, and after few changes on `build.gradle`, I started again get that error on IDE, but the build is finished successfully. The code is available here if you want take a look https://github.com/betorcs/sample-lambda-layer